# NVMe Arch Linux Dual Boot w/ Windows 10

Tags: arch-linux, windows, system-installation

I am installing Arch on my PC with Windows 10 as a dual boot. Windows 10 has a 120GB NVMe drive as the boot drive (C drive), along with a 2TB HDD. I have a completely separate 1TB NVMe drive that I am installing Arch on and so far I have my Arch NVMe drive formatted with Linux file system and swap. My issue is with mounting the Windows EFI system for dual boot. I cannot find an EFI system in my Windows NVMe device, but instead only see the type “HPFS/NTFS/exFAT” as partition 1 (/dev/nvme1n1p1) and the type “Hidden NTFS winRe” as partition 2 (/dev/nvme1n1p2). My question is which device should I mount to my Linux /mnt/efi directory I created to install Arch?

Edit: Not sure if this is different from the guides that I have been following because I’m using NVMe drives or if it is something to do with an EFI filesystem being under a different name.

Comment: Your p1 may be the ESP - efi system partition as FAT32, unless that is a recovery partition and your ESP is some other partition. Windows does not typically mount the ESP. Your p2 is the Microsoft System Reserved which must be unformatted & before the first Windows partition. I use Ubuntu and like to have an ESP on every drive, but that is not required. That a drive is NVMe should not matter, it still is a drive. Do you have a FAT32 partition? `sudo fdisk -lu` or `sudo gdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1`  or `sudo gdisk -l /dev/nvme1n1`

Comment: I have checked my drives and I do not believe any of them are FAT32 format. I am using cfdisk to partition my drives and I’m wondering if EFI may be listed under a different file system type. I looked through all the different possible format types in cfdisk and EFI isn’t a type. Any idea if one of those two file system types I listed above are the EFI system I’m looking for under a different name?

Comment: The UEFI standard requires the ESP to be FAT32. Did you change the format of some partition or delete a partiiton? If you have another partiition with /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi and other /EFI/xxxx boot files that would be the ESP, but it must be FAT32 for UEFI to read it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - My Windows 10 is installed as MBR/BIOS, which is why I’m not seeing an EFI partition. Just need to find a different guide on how to install Arch alongside a legacy install of Windows.